# Rails: render ruby logic in i18n string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml

I'm currently translating a application and i've stumbled upon a problem. I'm using this in my views:

```
t("page.text")
```

and i have this is my yaml file:

```
page:
  text: "This is my tekst with a #{link_to "pages index, pages_path}"
```

This string gets outputted without the link_to logic in it, like this: "This is my tekst with a #{link_to "pages index, pages_path}". This is not what i want, i want the string parsed with the link_to function like this:  "This is my tekst with a *pages index*" where pages index links to the /pages route...

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails's i18n API allows you to use variable-based interpolation in your YAML file. To do what you're trying to do:

```
# config/en.yml
page:
  text: "This is my test with a %{link}"

# view.html.erb
<%= t("page.text", :link => link_to("pages index", pages_path))
```

You can read more about it in the official Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation

Comment: I had to place an "_html" suffix to prevent the browser from escaping html tags. Something like text_html: "This is my test with a %{link}"

Comment: this won't handle translation of the "pages index" text on the link.  What's the best way to handle translating that?